# I'm trying to use the malloc function to allocate memory for an array but the the values aren't scanning in properly. Can anyone explain?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I was asked to write a program that tests whether a sequence of integers input by the user is a palindrome or not (reads same backwards as forwards). I can't figure out how to dynamically allocate memory so that the input can be of variable length. In the code you can see that the user enters the number of elements in their sequence, n. But during compilation, when n integers have been entered nothing happens. What is wrong with the code? Please explain in detail as much as possible, and if you know of any good references share them!! I'm struggling with pointers and arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int i, n, x; 
    int* intarray;
    printf("\nHow many integers are there?: \n");
    scanf("d", &n);
    intarray = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    printf("\nPlease enter the values:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &intarray[i]);
    }
    n = n - 1;
    x = n / 2;
    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (intarray[i] != intarray[n - i])
        {
            printf("\nThis is not a palindrome\n");
            return;
        }

        if (i = x)
        {
            printf("\nThis is a palindrome\n");
        }
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("d", &n);` is missing `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
 int i, n, x; 
 int* intarray;
 printf("\nHow many integers are there?: \n");
 scanf("%d", &n); // and as mentioned by all above type specifier % is missing in %d (for integer type)
 intarray = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
 printf("\nPlease enter the values:\n");
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
    scanf("%d", &intarray[i]);
 }
 n = n - 1;
 x = n / 2;
 for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
 { 
    if (intarray[i] != intarray[n - i])
    {
        printf("\nThis is not a palindrome\n");
        return;
    }

    if (i = x)
    {
        printf("\nThis is a palindrome\n");
    }
 }
return 0; // as your main()'s return type is int, you should should return an integer value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `scanf("d", &n);` statement that actually does not read anything into n as in order to read an integer you should use "%d" instead of "d".

Answer (score 0):

2 changes:

1.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

`%d` is the format specifier for scanning integers.

2.

```
intarray = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

No need to cast `malloc()`